# Camera Preview goes black after taking a photo

Tags: android, android-camera, freeze

In my Android app I want to take a photo. I have Samsung galaxy Gio (Android 2.3.3) and I was simply using `camera.takePicture(null, null, Activity.this);`, in my Activity I implemented `PictureCallback` method and everything was fine until I checked my app on Sony Xperia S (Android 4.0), on this phone the preview didn't freeze however it took a photo, so I add `camera.stopPreview()` function after taking a picture and now it was working fine on Xperia S but on my Samsung GIO after implementing this my screen after taking a photo goes black, does anyone have idea how to solve it ? Thanks for help

Here is my code:

When user clicks framelayout I use:

```
case R.id.camera_preview:
        camera.takePicture(null, null, Activity.this);
        break;
```

And in Activity i implemented picturecallback method:

```
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera arg1) {
    imageData = data;
    cam_preview.stopPreview();
}
```

I'm not saving image immediately because I'm giving user choice to save or not to save a picture

Comment: Please post your code. And link to the sample your using (if any)

Comment: I added some code, and I'm partially using this: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-essentials-create-a-mirror/?search_index=1

Answer (score 0):

From [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#takePicture(android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback, android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback, android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback, android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#takePicture%28android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback%29):

"Preview will be stopped after the image is taken; callers must call startPreview() again if they want to re-start preview or take more pictures."

So according to this the picture callback should be as follow:

```
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera arg1) {
     imageData = data;
     cam_preview.startPreview();
}
```

Comment: But it will restart a preview, I want to freeze it and then decide to save it or not

Comment: Ok then you could check android.os.Build.MODEL to determine the device model, then decide whether or not to stop the preview (Xperia S versus Samsung GIO)